# Static context error

Tags: c#

I can't figure out what could be static here to cause that error below:

```
public bool OptionsMatch(Item item, ItemFavorite itemFavorite)
{
    bool isSame = true;

    switch (item.DispType)
    {
        case DispType.Dropdown:
        case DispType.Radio:
            isSame = String.Contains(item.Value);
            break;
        case DispType.ImageList:
            isSame = ListValuesMatch(item, itemFavorite);
            break;
    }

    return isSame;
}
```

**Error:** Cannot access non-static method 'Contains' in static context

DispType is an enum.  And the rest are all non-static concrete type instances as well as the underlying class is not static either that contains this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string.Contains` is not static, it is an instance method; i.e. it is called on an *instance* of a string, like so:

```
"something".Contains(item.Value);
```

This is because `Contains` requires two objects - the reference string, and the string to search for. You've only provided one (the string to search for) but not where to look.

Comment: I don't know how many times I've done this to myself with contains.  It's so damn obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem which occurs:

```
isSame = String.Contains(item.Value);
```

[Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) is an instance method:

```
isSame = "foo".Contains(item.Value);
```

or the other way around depending on what you are trying to do:

```
isSame = item.Value.Contains("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Contains` is not a valid static method.  What are you trying to evaluate?

Answer (score 0):

The method `Contains` on `System.String` is an instance method.  You're trying to access using the type `System.String` which is an error.  You'll need an instance of string.